# Joystick D-Pad not working on sdlmame

Tags: controllers, linux, emulation

I wasn't sure on which StackExchange site I should ask this, so I'll give it a try over here.

I installed sdlmame (0.140-1) and qmc2 (0.2.b17-1) as a frontend on ArchLinux.

I enabled a USB joystick control on the Options screen and calibrated it. I had to uncheck axises 0, 1, 4 and 5 since they are not working. I am using a regular USB gamepad with a D-Pad (direction controller) and 10 action buttons which are being detected correctly (or so it seems in the Test screen). Axises 2 and 3 seem to be working.

When I load a ROM, the action buttons are working fine, but the D-Pad has no reaction at all. It's weird since the test page shows the expected reaction to the pressing of the D-Pad, but I have no D-Pad functionality whatsoever in the games.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using this MAME setup on Linux Mint 10 (Ubuntu):

SDLMAME with QMC2 frontend; xboxdrv to use my USB XBOX360 controller; QJoyPad for some non-MAME control of my desktop.

QJoyPad could help your problems, but first try this: When you're in a playable game screen (in MAME), hit the TAB key and map universal or individual game controls directly from there.

QJoyPad is the Xpadder of Linux; not as fancy, but if you need to use your controller in the desktop or want to do a fast, quick-and-dirty remap of the 1, 5, ESC, and ENTER keys plus joysticks/D-Pad for MAME, it'll work.

You'll know you've found the right combo of programs/settings when you can easily play Robotron with your controller. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try a program called "**Xppader**"

Has helped me in many games.